# How to force procedure name to be in small caps

Tags: fonts, algorithms, algorithmic, algpseudocode

When using `algorithm` environment:

```
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
  \caption{Title}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \Procedure{\textsc{Graph}}{$ \alpha, \beta $}    
    \State ...
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The name of the procedure `\Procedure{\textsc{Graph}}` always appears in capital letters even if I use `\textsc{}`. How can I force it to be in small caps?

Comment: Have you tried `\Procedure{\mbox{\textsc{Graph}}}`?

Comment: @Mico Thank you Mico. I just tried it but it didn't fix. BTW, I am using IEEE cls, does that matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `algpseudocode` style has

```
\algnewcommand\textproc{\textsc}
```

Thus adding `\textsc` does nothing more. Just change this definition.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algrenewcommand\textproc{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
  \caption{Title}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \Procedure{Graph}{$ \alpha, \beta $}
    \State ...
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: question asks to force Graph to be in Small caps and you showed how to remove that?